# inputing many objects into core data in one go

Tags: database, object, core-data, swift3, attributes

I have many objects I would like to put into a core data attribute in one go, is there a quick way of doing this? I know you use this system to create the objects but you have to run it again and again to add the new objects.

```
       let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

   let newName = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "StoredNames", into: context)

    newName.setValue("Jim", forKey: "name")
```

is there a quick solution to this? a way I can add many names into the name attribute in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan to use `NSPersistentContainer` you should treat `viewContext` as readonly.  If you want to insert into core-data you should use `performBackgroundTask` which gives you a context to insert with.  Do all your inserting in that block and call save **once** at the end.  This will avoid multiple saves to core-data.

```
 let lotsOfStuffToInsert = ["Eugenio Barefoot",
        "Shaquita Lettieri",
        "Tami Hollingworth",
        "Marion Pruitt",
        "Hubert Pigeon",
        "Stewart Christon",
        "Clarence Murry",
        "Roni Bohnsack",
        "Mozell Oberman",
        "Mellissa Dowd",
        "Sybil Swinton"]
self.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { (managedObjectContext) in
    for name in lotsOfStuffToInsert{
        let newName = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "StoredNames", into: managedObjectContext)
        newName.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    }
    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch {

    }
}
```

also make sure to add in you core-data setup

```
container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean, are you able to demonstrate with some code? I've never come across performBackgrounTask before

Comment: Great example names in a great answer.